# JavaScript Canvas Zoom

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following canvas (actually it is an image inside):

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1600"></canvas>
```

I tried to integrate the first example like:
http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

But it doesn't work because of `data-zoom-image` I think so.

**How I can do a simple zoom on canvas object on mouse over?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is important to clearify, that You would like to zoom to the area, where the pointer stands at, or zoom simply to a static area.

Comment: Where the pointer stands at. Like the first example in the link. Thanks

Comment: I've answered a very similar question to this before, and its quite simple if you have some JavaScript knowledge. [**Check out my accepted answer here!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653382/zoom-my-drawing-on-the-background/24654806#24654806). I have a JSFiddle for the project within the comments at the bottom (I would follow the last one). Hope that helps!